# Extracting numeric values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to transform a column ('Price') that may have multiple numeric values for price (e.g. USD500-750). I need to extract those and find their mean, excluding calendar years (e.g.2019). Sometimes the value includes a string (e.g. USD500), sometimes it is blank, sometimes it is only numeric (e.g. 500).

Currently, I am doing it like this:

```
s=df['Price'].str.findall('\d+')
df['Price'] = s.apply(lambda x: np.mean([float(i) for i in x if int(i)<2000]))
```

However, this only works if there is a string in the value (e.g. USD500), and does not work for blanks, or for numeric only (e.g. 500).

How do I amend this that it would work for any type?

Thanks

Edit: Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Price": ["Above Market Price", "USD200K as an initial price", "USD310K to 360K.", 300000, "", "150,000"]
```

First 3 would work, last 3 would not.

If I only had the first 3, the output would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Output": ["", 200, 335]
```

But if you add the last 3 it does not work

Final expected output, but I don't need the last 3 to be divided by 3 yet, I just need to get past the hurdle of the code not working on blanks and if it's only numeric, at the moment it only works if there is string in the code:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({
            "Output": ["", 200, 335, 300, "", 150]
```

Comment: How can we distinguish between `2019` meaning a currency amount and `2019` meaning a year?

Comment: Currency will never (or rarely) be over 1000, and almost certainly not over 2000. I guess I could do 2000<x<2025 or something

Comment: @lala345, post a testable `df['Price']`

Comment: this `310K` means `310000`, do you count on that? It should be skipped (as it's not `<2000`)?

Comment: I know, the plan is to divide any of these by 1000, the price will always be around 100k-600k, so if the number is bigger than 1000 (or say 3000 to avoid year problems) I will divide it by 1000

Comment: Why are there years in the Price column? Sod's Law says that if you rely on heuristics, you are going to get caught out.

Comment: @lala345, "*the price will always be around 100k-600k*" - in that case the last value `"150,000"` is also a valid value as it's just `150K`. Would you retain it?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes exactly, but the code does not work

Comment: @lala345, considering all the nuances we were discovering in above comments, update the full expected result

Comment: Edited with the full expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With complex substitutions (`str.replace`) and regex matching (`str.findall`):

```
def extract_prices(prices):
    prices = (prices.astype(str).str.replace(r',', '')
             .replace(r'(?<=\d)K', '000', regex=True).str.findall(r'\d+')
             .str.join(' ').str.split(' ', expand=True).replace('', np.nan)
             .astype(float).div(1000))
    prices = prices.where(prices < 2000).mean(axis=1)
    return prices

print(extract_prices(df['Price']))
```

---

```
0      NaN
1    200.0
2    335.0
3    300.0
4      NaN
5    150.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a vectorised approach that uses regular expression extraction. I assume that that comma is a thousands-separator.

```py
import re

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Price": [
        "Above Market Price",            # excluded
        "USD200K as an initial price",   # 200000
        "USD310K to 360K.",              # mean of (310000, 360000)
        300000,                          # 300000
        "",                              # excluded
        "150,000",                       # 150000
        "2019",                          # excluded
    ]
})

terms = (
    df['Price'].astype(str)
    .str.replace(',', '')  # Interpret comma as digit group separator
    .str.extractall(pat=r'(\d+k?)', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    [0].str.lower()        # Normalize case for 'K'
    .str.replace('k', '000')
    .astype(float)
)
terms = terms[(terms < 2000) | (terms > 2200)].groupby(level=0).mean()
print(terms)
```

```
1    200000.0
2    335000.0
3    300000.0
5    150000.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

This format has original indices where values have been extracted, with gaps where no values were extracted.

Comment: your final result is not as the OP has requested (`["", 200, 335, 300, "", 150]`)

Comment: That's deliberate. When manipulating data in a frame (prior to presentation), quantities should always be at the unary scale; and mixing empty strings and numerals is regressive and has some of the same data smells as OP's input.